# Display objects with the same key in one row

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I got this objects

```
{"key":["0114","1","2013"],"values":["279"]},
{"key":["0114","1","2014"],"values":["235"]},
{"key":["0114","1","2015"],"values":["258"]},
{"key":["0114","1","2016"],"values":["274"]},
{"key":["0114","1","2017"],"values":["293"]}
```

0114 is a county in sweden.

1 is symbolizes men

2013... is the years

values is the amount of men born in ex. 2013

I want to display them like this:
[image: pic1]

How it looks right now:
[image]

How i'm displaying rightnow :

```
    <div class="tabellWrapper">
            <table class="kommunerMainWrapper" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td >Kommun</td>
                        <th >Kön</th>
                        <th >2013</th>
                        <th >2014</th>
                        <th >2015</th>
                        <th >2016</th>
                        <th >2017</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="kommunerWrapper" >
                    <template v-for="(data,index) in selectedLanData">
                        <tr v-if="data.key[1] ==='1'" :key="index">
                            <th class="kommunerItem kommun">{{data.key[0]}}</th>
                            <th class="kommunerItem sex" >Män</th>
                            <th class="kommunerItem numbers">{{data.values[0]}}</th>
                            <th class="kommunerItem numbers">{{data.key[2]}}</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr v-else :key="index">
                            <th class="kommunerItem kommun">{{data.key[0]}}</th>
                            <th class="kommunerItem sex" >Kvinnor</th>
                            <th class="kommunerItem numbers">{{data.values[0]}}</th>
                            <th class="kommunerItem numbers">{{data.key[2]}}</th>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should parse your data array before. If it is a possibility for you, this could be the code:

```js
var source = [
    {"key":["0114","1","2013"],"values":["279"]},
    {"key":["0114","1","2014"],"values":["235"]},
    {"key":["0114","1","2015"],"values":["258"]},
    {"key":["0114","1","2016"],"values":["274"]},
    {"key":["0114","1","2017"],"values":["293"]}
];

var parsed = {};

for (var i=0; i<source.length; i++) {
    var key = source[i].key;
    if (!(source[i].key[0] in parsed)) {
        parsed[source[i].key[0]] = {};
    }
    if (!(source[i].key[1] in parsed[source[i].key[0]])) {
        parsed[source[i].key[0]][source[i].key[1]] = {};
    }
    if (!(source[i].key[2] in parsed[source[i].key[0]][source[i].key[1]])) {
        parsed[source[i].key[0]][source[i].key[1]][source[i].key[2]] = 0;
    }
    parsed[source[i].key[0]][source[i].key[1]][source[i].key[2]] += parseInt(source[i].values);
}

console.log(parsed);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function as so:

```js
const data = [
    {"key":["0114","1","2013"],"values":["279"]},
    {"key":["0114","1","2014"],"values":["235"]},
    {"key":["0114","1","2015"],"values":["258"]},
    {"key":["0114","1","2016"],"values":["274"]},
    {"key":["0114","1","2017"],"values":["293"]}
];

const tableRows = data.reduce((rows, value) => {
  let currentRow = rows.find(row => row.region === value.key[0] && row.gender === value.key[1]);
  if (!currentRow) {
    currentRow = {region: value.key[0], gender: value.key[1]};
    rows.push(currentRow);
  }
  currentRow[value.key[2]] = value.values[0];
  return rows;
}, []);

console.log(tableRows);
```